# HTML tags in title - SharePoint 2010

Tags: html, sharepoint

*using SharePoint 2010 web editor*

I created a (sub-menu) page with title **CO<sub>2</sub>**. When rendered in browser, the title of the page is: **CO<sub>2</sub>** whereas the menu item shows **CO<sub>2</sub>**.

Apparently it is escaping the HTML tags in page but rendering correctly inside the menu.

How to make the page title looks same as menu item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tags are recognized in a title element by HTML rules (and by browser practice); they are indeed rendered as such. In principle, you can use special characters like “₂” SUBSCRIPT TWO U+2082 in a title element. You can even denote them using character references:

```
<title>CO&#x2082;</title>
```

However, only some fonts support SUBSCRIPT TWO, and it is quite possible that the rendering of title elements e.g. in a browser top bar or tab label uses a font that does not support to it. In that case, a rectangle, vertical bar, space, or other generic indicator of missing glyph probably appears.

Note that the appearance is usually not quite the same as in the menu, since browsers implement `sup` by reducing font size and putting the glyph in a lower position. Only by accident would this coincide with the design of “₂” in a font. But if the texts are displayed in two different fonts, as they probably are, this is usually not a serious problem.